# How to Just select one data duplicates in Foreach Codeiginiter

Tags: codeigniter

hay i have result like this

[image]

But i want to remove duplicates keterangan and just display one data , i expected like this

[image]

**keterangan** is unique so just display one data , how do like this ?

this is my controllers

```
public function print_cashier($id)
{


    $get_allData = $this->Approval_management_model->getDataCashier($id);
    $data['resultsAll'] = $get_allData;
```

}

method getDataCashier() from query like this :

```
 function getDataCashier($id)
{
    $this->db->select(',
    a.jenis_jurnal,
    a.no_perkiraan,
    c.nama,
    a.keterangan,
    b.potongan,
    b.potongan_note,
    b.coa_potongan,
    b.coa_lain,
    b.biaya_lain_note,
    a.debet,
    a.kredit,
    d.username');
    $this->db->from('jurnal a');
    $this->db->join('tr_new_purchase_order_payment as b', 'a.no_request=b.no_request', 'left');
    $this->db->join('coa_master as c', 'a.no_perkiraan=c.no_perkiraan', 'left');
    $this->db->join('users as d', 'b.created_by=d.id_user', 'left');
    $this->db->where('a.jenis_jurnal', 'pembayaran');
    $this->db->where('b.id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
   
}
```

this is result form   var_dump($data['resultsAll'])

```
    array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[40]
      public 'keterangan' => string 'PEMBELIAN Cash Advance U/CA-2020-0045 TGL PR. 2020-12-31' (length=56)
      public 'jenis_jurnal' => string 'pembayaran' (length=10)
      public 'no_perkiraan' => string '1101-01-01' (length=10)
      public 'nama' => string 'Kas Kecil - GA' (length=14)
      public 'potongan' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'potongan_note' => string 'bbbbb' (length=5)
      public 'coa_potongan' => string '7204-02-01' (length=10)
      public 'coa_lain' => string '7206-01-01' (length=10)
      public 'biaya_lain_note' => string 'bbb' (length=3)
      public 'debet' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'kredit' => string '-9998' (length=5)
      public 'username' => string 'Firman' (length=6)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'keterangan' => string 'PEMBELIAN Cash Advance U/CA-2020-0045 TGL PR. 2020-12-31' (length=56)
      public 'jenis_jurnal' => string 'pembayaran' (length=10)
      public 'no_perkiraan' => string '7204-02-01' (length=10)
      public 'nama' => string 'Provisi Bank' (length=12)
      public 'potongan' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'potongan_note' => string 'bbbbb' (length=5)
      public 'coa_potongan' => string '7204-02-01' (length=10)
      public 'coa_lain' => string '7206-01-01' (length=10)
      public 'biaya_lain_note' => string 'bbb' (length=3)
      public 'debet' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'kredit' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'username' => string 'Firman' (length=6)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[42]
      public 'keterangan' => string 'PEMBELIAN Cash Advance U/CA-2020-0045 TGL PR. 2020-12-31' (length=56)
      public 'jenis_jurnal' => string 'pembayaran' (length=10)
      public 'no_perkiraan' => string '2105-02-01' (length=10)
      public 'nama' => string 'Hutang PPH 21 Pegawai' (length=21)
      public 'potongan' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'potongan_note' => string 'bbbbb' (length=5)
      public 'coa_potongan' => string '7204-02-01' (length=10)
      public 'coa_lain' => string '7206-01-01' (length=10)
      public 'biaya_lain_note' => string 'bbb' (length=3)
      public 'debet' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'kredit' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'username' => string 'Firman' (length=6)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[43]
      public 'keterangan' => string 'PEMBELIAN Cash Advance U/CA-2020-0045 TGL PR. 2020-12-31' (length=56)
      public 'jenis_jurnal' => string 'pembayaran' (length=10)
      public 'no_perkiraan' => string '7206-01-01' (length=10)
      public 'nama' => string 'Biaya Lainnya' (length=13)
      public 'potongan' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'potongan_note' => string 'bbbbb' (length=5)
      public 'coa_potongan' => string '7204-02-01' (length=10)
      public 'coa_lain' => string '7206-01-01' (length=10)
      public 'biaya_lain_note' => string 'bbb' (length=3)
      public 'debet' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'kredit' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'username' => string 'Firman' (length=6)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[44]
      public 'keterangan' => string 'PEMBELIAN Cash Advance U/CA-2020-0045 TGL PR. 2020-12-31' (length=56)
      public 'jenis_jurnal' => string 'pembayaran' (length=10)
      public 'no_perkiraan' => string '6204-03-01' (length=10)
      public 'nama' => string 'Pemeliharaan Peralatan' (length=22)
      public 'potongan' => string '10000' (length=5)
      public 'potongan_note' => string 'bbbbb' (length=5)
      public 'coa_potongan' => string '7204-02-01' (length=10)
      public 'coa_lain' => string '7206-01-01' (length=10)
      public 'biaya_lain_note' => string 'bbb' (length=3)
      public 'debet' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'kredit' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'username' => string 'Firman' (length=6)
```

when use group_by just return one data for all column ,,

help. thanks

Comment: I have a php solution (not mysql) - can i see how you populate that table -- OR the `print_r($get_allData)` - (pls put in your question)

Comment: i already update the question, @Kinglish

Comment: why it has a lot of same data, why its duplicated, is all the data is the same or it has different things to show?

Answer (score 0):

Im from Indonesian and i khow that is like a *general journal* a part of *Indonesian Accounting Standar*. I see you want to show a journal, right? Or you want to show a ledger for *Pemeliharaan Mobil*?

I think you miss some extra table for some relation.

Try this :

**Controller :**

```
public function print_cashier($id)
{
$get_allData = $this->Approval_management_model->getDataCashier($id);
$get_oneData = $this->Approval_management_model->getDataCashierOne($id);
$data['resultsAll'] = $get_allData;
$data['resultsOne'] = $get_oneData; // Get one row
}
```

**In Model, add this method :**

```
 function getDataCashierOne($id)
{
     $this->db->select(',
     a.no_perkiraan,c.nama,a.keterangan,
     b.coa_lain,b.biaya_lain_note,
     d.username');
     $this->db->from('jurnal a');
     $this->db->join('tr_new_purchase_order_payment as b', 
     'a.no_request=b.no_request', 'left');
     $this->db->join('coa_master as c', 'a.no_perkiraan=c.no_perkiraan', 'left');
     $this->db->join('users as d', 'b.created_by=d.id_user', 'left');
     $this->db->where('a.jenis_jurnal', 'pembayaran');
     $this->db->where('b.id', $id);

     $query = $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

**In View :**

```
<div class = "row"> <!-- If Bootstrap -->
  <div class = "col-md-2">
         <?php foreach($resultAll as $all){
              echo $all->no_perkiraan;
         }?> 
  </div>

  <div class = "col-md-2">
         <?php foreach($resultAll as $all){
              echo $all->nama;
         }?> 
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-6">
         <?php // This is one row data
          echo $one->keterangan; 
          ?> 
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-4"> 
         <?php foreach($resultAll as $all){
              echo $all->debet;
              // kredit field and also tugas field here
              // Use span class or your css class for layout
         }?> 
  </div>
</div>
```